# How to check if array sent via post in php

Tags: php, html

This is my html page --

```
<select name="search_by_manager[]" data-placeholder="Search by Manager" multiple class="select2">
<?php
$result = $linkID1->query("select user_id,fullname from user_details order by user_id asc")
or
die("error");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    echo "<option value='$row[user_id]'>$row[fullname]</option>";
}
 ?>
</select>
```

This is my php page where data is posted --

```
if(!empty($_POST["search_by_manager"]))
{
    $search_by_manager = $_POST["search_by_manager"];
    $flag2 = 1;

    $limit = count($search_by_manager);

    for($i=0;$i<$limit;$i++)
    {
        $search_by_manager[$i] = mysql_real_escape_string($search_by_manager[$i]);
        $qry_manager = "'";
        $qry_manager .= "$search_by_manager[$i]";
        $qry_manager .= "',";
    }
    $qry_manager = substr($qry_manager,0,-1);
}
```

Here the problem is that, its not getting inside the if block, how to check whether values sent via post or not. Normal data can be easily checked using isset() function but how to check whether post array is empty or not.

Comment: You may like to lookup `foreach` as well for processing all of an array its a lot easier

Comment: First try to print and see the format of your POST array data => print_r($_POST) then decide how put this in if condition.